# in_array() performance optimization

Tags: php, performance, optimization

I have the following condition:

```
if(in_array($needle, $haystack) ||
    in_array($needle . "somePostfix", $haystack) ||
    in_array($needle . "someOtherPostfix", $haystack) ||
    // and some more) {
    // do something
}
```

My haystack contains more than 10k elements, and this check takes about 400ms. I know that `in_array` has to iterate over the whole array multiple times. In my case the common case is that the element is not found. and I tried to improve this by creating the following method that only iterates once over the haystack:

```
function wildcardInArray($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $value) {
        if (true === fnmatch($needle . '*', $haystack)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this decreases my performance even more, seems to me that `fnmatch` is the bottleneck.

Is there any improvement for this case of array search?

Comment: Would `array_diff` and/or `array_intersect` help here?

Comment: What if, instead of `fnmatch` you do: `$value === $needle || $value === $needle . "somePostfix" || $value === $needle . "someOtherPostfix"`? Any sort of pattern matching is going to be slower than a straight up `===`

Comment: Have you tried using the array as a map instead (with like 1 as value)? It was quite some time since I did php, but that would probably be a lot faster.

Comment: Have you tried `array_reduce($array, function($found, $el){ return $found && ($el === 'val1' || $el === 'val2'); })` ?

Comment: @Halcyon you are right I didn't think about this, but is there also any generic solution?
I have not tryed to use a map or array_reduce

Comment: Why not `implode()` and `strpos()`?

Comment: @bpoiss a generic solution is in the area of hashmaps or other fast indexes. `in_array` is about as ineffecient as you can get. If you want to do pattern matching like `foo*` you'll need a more involved (and likely slower) solution, because it's a harder problem.

Comment: seems like the array is taken from database, wouldn't optimize your query will yield to a better result ??

Comment: My array doesn't come from database it comes from a webservice I can not touch.

Comment: @Gearloose how much faster will it be with implode() and strpos()?

Comment: I was able devise a unique array of just 1300 unique values, so the results might be biased. I looped the methods for 10000 times and found:
`array_search` = 0.22s - 0.25s,
`in_array` = 0.22s - 0.23s
`strpos(implode())` = 0.47s - 0.51s.

The main advantage of `strpos()` is the inexact search. Results vary greatly per server / data set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very interesting question that doesn't appear to have a great answer. I did some very unscientific bench-marking and I was not able to get any faster than `in_array` for a `$haystack` with 100000 elements.

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2015 01:34:46) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans

Sorting Time*:    0.19367408752441
Imploding Time**: 0.0207359790802
preg_match:       0.10927486419678
needle ===:       0.083639144897461
in_array:         0.019428968429565
array_flip:       0.028955936431885
array_intersect:  0.15198707580566
array_diff:       0.15532493591309

//*sort without search (binary search wouldn't add much time)
//**time it took to implode the array 
//     (no search was performed, this search WOULD take significant time if implemented)
```

As you can see, only three of these methods took less than 100ms, `needle ===`, `in_array` and `array_flip`. And out of these three, `in_array` was clearly the fastest. Now the question is how many postfix-es do you have? The running time on `in_array` will be `O(n*m)` (`n` is size of your haystack, `m` is the number of postfixes), which is a problem if `m` is also very large. If `m` is significantly large, sorting the data once and performing a binary search on the sorted list will be `O(m*log(n))` which grows much slower, but has a higher initial overhead as shown in the sorting time above. Even better, if you have a very large `m` would probably be `array_flip` as each search should only take `O(1)` lookup after the initial flip.

### CODE

*Haystack creation*

```
$haystack = array();

function getRandomWord($len = 10) {
        $len = rand(3,10);
        $word = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z'));
            shuffle($word);
            return substr(implode($word), 0, $len);
}

$numWords = 100000;
for($i = 0; $i < $numWords; $i++) {
    $haystack[] = getRandomWord();
}
```

*TESTs*

```
//*Sorting*    
$copy = $haystack;
sort($copy);


//implode    
$copy = implode($haystack, " ");


//*preg_match_test*
function preg_match_test($regex, $haystack) {
    $matches = false;
    foreach($haystack as $value) {
        if (preg_match($regex, $value)) {
            $matches = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $matches;
}

//needle ===
function equalsNeedle($needles, $haystack) {
    $matches = false;
    foreach ($haystack as $value) {
        foreach($needles as $needle) {
            if ($needle === $value) {
                $matches = true;
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return $matches;
}

//in_array
function baseCase($needles, $haystack) {
    $matches = false;
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
        if (in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
            $matches = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $matches;
}

//array_flip
function arrayFlipping($needles, $haystack) {
    $matches = false;
    $copy = array_flip($haystack);
    foreach ($needles as $needle) {
        if (array_key_exists($needle, $copy)) {
            $matches = true;
        }
    }
    return $matches;
}

//array_intersect
function arrayIntersect($needles, $haystack) {
    if (count(array_intersect($needles, $haystack)) > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//array_diff
function arrayDiff($needles, $haystack) {
    if (count(array_diff($needles, $haystack)) !== count($needles)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

*Calling Code*

```
$array = array("foo","foobar","foobazz","foobuzz");
$base = "foo";
$regex = "/^$base(bizz|bazz|buzz|)$/";

echo "preg_match: ";
preg_match_test($regex, $haystack);
echo "needle === ";
equalsNeedle($array, $haystack);
echo "in_array:  ";
baseCase($array, $haystack);
echo "array_flip:  ";
arrayFlipping($array, $haystack);
echo "array_intersect:  ";
arrayIntersect($array, $haystack);
echo "array_diff:  ";
arrayDiff($array, $haystack);
```

All tests were wrapped with timing code using `microtime(true)`.

Comment: How should your function `baseCase` even work? I see `return $t;` but $t is never declared. And `arrayFlipping` will always return false.

Comment: @bpoiss, you are correct, I was a little sloppy when I copied them over. I wrote most of them as proof of concepts so there were a few little errors. I will make the edits for completeness. Thanks for bringing them to my attention.

Comment: You should disable both opcache as well as xdebug to even have some way of a benchmark that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

You can use your array as 'keys', i.e:

`$arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', … ];` to `$arr = ['a' => true, 'b' => true, …]`.

You will consume more memory but you will have an instant result with `isset($arr[$key]);`.

Fastest but biggest in memory, you can use stdClass and `isset($obj->$key);`

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->{'a'} = true;
$obj->{'b'} = true;
$obj->{'…'} = true;
```

If you can't change your array structure, tell us if you can sort manually the array contents?

```
// generic
$length = strlen($needle);
$char = $needle[0];
$found = false;
$suffixes = [ false, 'somePostfix', 'someOtherPostfix' ];

foreach($haystack as $entry) {
  if ($char === $entry[0] && $needle === substr($entry, 0, $length)) {
    $suffix = substr($entry, $length);
    if (in_array($suffix, $suffixes, true)) {
      $found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How much performance improvments will I get? Have you any benchmark tests for this?