# Why xdebug marks 587 and 588 as not executed and 589 as executed?

Tags: php, xdebug, php-7, xdebug-profiler

This is the chunk of code with the issue
[image]

And this is the legend
[image]

Comment: Are you asking why it marked 2 lines as not executed but the third line was executed?

Comment: Yes, I am. Why?

Comment: Btw: you want to use in_array() instead of your current lenghty chain of conditions.

Comment: You should include that clarification in your question. I would imagine that the downvotes are due to lack of clarifying your question.

Comment: I thought it was obvious.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa The PHP tag gets a lot of crap every single minute so relying on people to spot the "obvious" is not a good idea. I am genuinely confused why xdebug is behaving like that but I would imagine that their support channel can tell you: https://xdebug.org/support.php

Comment: If you don't believe me about the amount of crap PHP questions then just check out how many questions have been asked since you posted this. There are 100 new questions ahead of yours.

Comment: That almost sounds like discrimination. People don't pay attention anymore, these days. It's easier to judge than to take some time to understand.

Comment: BTW @MarcinOrlowski `in_array` is slower https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205363/in-array-performance-optimization/35205873

Comment: Discrimination? Be my guest and open up that discussion on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Everyone here volunteers their time so if you wish to make the community better then I invite you to spend more time answering questions and filtering the noise. The unfortunate fact is that for every good question there are at least 100 crap questions so selective attention and speed play a key role in volunteers maintaining their sanity. If you feel entitled to quality then please exhibit the quality which you expect.

Comment: By the way, I am not saying that your question is bad by any means but the lack of early clarification most likely resulted in downvotes and I doubt that the view count on this will surpass 40. It's just the nature of the beast known as Stack Overflow

Comment: @andrei sure, critically slow. Esp. With 4 elements array, lol. Read the question you link to again. He had 10k elements there.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski that 4 elements array is in a loop which is in another loop so do the math.

Comment: Benchmark yourself.

Comment: I don't have to. There are already a lot of examples on the web. http://www.w3programmers.com/phps-in_array-function-is-really-slow/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've understood what happens. The line 586 has multiple conditions and not all cases are covered and for those cases that are not covered 587 and 588 are listed as not executed.

The legend should be updated though because is confusing.